# In Expo, Requiring module "fetch", threw an exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: self

Tags: react-native, fetch, expo, npm-scripts

I have searched across different possible answers, but didn't find any appropriate addressing this specific error.

I have mentioned the exact error string in the question title. This error started appearing when I installed `fetch` npm module in my `ReactNative` app. This error appears just at the time app is launched/loaded on my phone during development. Before installing `fetch`, my app was loading correctly on the phone. In windows CLI there is no such error that assist me to resolve the issue, it just shows the build is successful.

I am using `Expo` for my `ReactNative` app development. Please assist in this regard to resolve the issue. Further details can be seen in following attached screen (that shows stack trace):

[image: Expo error on app load]

**Package.json**

```
{
    "name": "my-new-project",
    "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "eject": "expo eject",
        "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "jest-expo"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
        "expo": "29.0.0",
        "fetch": "^1.1.0",
        "react": "16.3.1",
        "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-29.0.0.tar.gz",
        "react-navigation": "^2.9.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "jest-expo": "29.0.0"
    }
}
```

This is a quite strange issue, that when I **Uninstall** `fetch` and try to use any other library e.g. `axios`, the reference to same error (related to fetch module) still appears. I have restarted my laptop machine, and restarted `Expo` app on mobile as well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have figured it out, basically it was not the `npm` neither the *NPM* `fetch` component issue. Basically after setting up the project I ran `npm install expo-cli` which message was appearing in CLI when I try to run `expo start` or `npm start`. At this time there was new version available `v30.x.x`, and YES the `self` reference issue was in older `expo` version but not in `v30.x.x`.

After installing `expo-cli` it was not matching to my existing project expo configuration and installed files, hence I re-setup the project again, which loaded and installed latest version libraries and coppied the project files into it.

And boom! The application ran without any error this time.

Comment: For me upgrading to expo-cli@2.2.0 produced this error. Downgrading to expo-cli@2.1.3 got it working again.

Comment: This issue persists in expo `v32.0.0`. Downgrading is not really a solution.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue is produced by the fresh version of `whatwg-fetch`. The solutions, which works for me is explicit adding the older version:

`npm i whatwg-fetch@2.0.4`

or

`yarn add whatwg-fetch@2.0.4`

Solution taken from [here](https://github.com/getsentry/react-native-sentry/issues/424#issuecomment-435445187)

Answer (score 1):

On my side, the error was triggered each time I shut down and restart the pc (I develop on Ubuntu 16.04 ).

I used an old answer ( 2016 ) which completely fixed the issue:

I added:

```
global.self = global;
```

into the main `js` file.

And everything is back to normal.

`expo-cli` is at `2.2.4` ( last version )

Comment: You didn't added the reference to the detailed answer which helped you fix the problem. Also, it is better if you past the new main `.js` file syntax showing where exactly you added this.

Comment: The above worked well for me. I added the line into my `App.js` after imports and everything was golden

Answer (score 0):

I think fetch 1.1.0 cannot work well on React Native because React Native use JS core not NodeJS.
I prefer you use library `axios` or built-in 'fetch' of React Native (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html).

`npm install axios --save`

Example

```
// Want to use async/await? Add the `async` keyword to your outer function/method.
async function getUser() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get('/user?ID=12345');
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

or

```
const axios = require('axios');

// Make a request for a user with a given ID
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });

// Optionally the request above could also be done as
axios.get('/user', {
    params: {
      ID: 12345
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

Comment: This is quite strange that I have *uninstalled* `fetch` and also reinstalled `expo-cli` (globally) but the reference to **self** error is still there. It seems like I have to recreate whole project from scratch. I also run `npm cache clean --force` but no success. Any suggestion?

Comment: I think you still need delete node_modules and install again with `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm install`. And need restart dev server again. I prefer start dev server with command `npm start --reset-cache` or `yarn start --reset-cache`

Comment: I have removed *node_modules/* directory. Restarted machine, then run `npm install` but no success. Same issue I originally posted.
However you mentioned `npm start`, this does not work correctly from last few days on my machine, and for that I have posted a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534354/expo-cli-is-installed-globally-but-npm-start-command-still-asks