# Expo CLI is installed globally but "npm start" command still asks

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I have installed `expo-cli` globally. But when I try to run command `npm start` it still asks to install `expo-cli` globally. Why?

I have reinstalled `expo-cli` again but same issue, even after machine restart.

Here is the screenshot for further details:

[image: Expo CLI]

Comment: I think you need install by yourself with command `npm install -g expo-cli`. Sometime this yes/no question not work correct.

Comment: I tried this as well, and then also restarted my machine. But no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually as I reinstalled `expo-cli` which was an updated version and was not matching with the project files, as the project was initialized using `expo init`.

I created another directory, reinitialized using `expo init` and now `npm stat` command works like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

The same happened to me, I just started using `expo start` instead of `npm start` and is working now.

Comment: Basically `npm start` does not work sometimes and ask to installed `expo-cli` globally (even though it is installed globally). This happens due to some compatibility version mismatch between `npm` and `expo-cli`. But yes it is correct to use `expo start` command to start the `expo` packager.

Comment: @MuhammadHannan If that is the case, how to make `npm` and `expo-cli` versions to be compatible? I am using `yarn` and having the same issue.

Comment: :)  Normally i noticed that the `npm start` command works only when you recently installed fresh copy of `expo-cli` and you just recently initialized your project. If, I'm not wrong, you can try *reinitializing* your project directory (if its a running project). I guess it shows warning after checking project files. But if you are using `expo start` that is good way as well, and you can gear up your project development without any issue.

Answer (score 2):

A local install of `expo-cli` worked for me despite the request for a global install...

```
npm install expo-cli
npm start
```

Subsequently, the expo command may not be available in path but can be reference directly as follows:

```
node_modules/expo-cli/bin/expo.js ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a problem with the version of expo-cli that it tries to install when you answer the question, try to install this version: `npm i -g expo-cli@3.5.0`, it worked perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use Powershell with this command : 
"npm install expo-cli --global".

If you have used Powershell with this command and it does not work, try on CMD with:
"npm install expo-cli -g"

Answer (score 0):

For me it was an environment variable problem; After installing expo cli, I had to open a new command line to make it work.