# NPM Start always ask me to install Expo CLI while I already have installed in globally

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, expo

-npm start

=This command requires Expo CLI.
=Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expo CLI is installed globally but "npm start" command still asks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534354/expo-cli-is-installed-globally-but-npm-start-command-still-asks)