# Endless loop on installing Expo CLI

Tags: react-native, expo

I try to execute command `npm start` on terminal on my Mac. 
It prompts me to install Expo CLI , I say Y,  wait until installation to finish, then I end up in an endless loop where it keeps prompting me to install Expo CLI again:

```
This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]? y
Installing the package 'expo-cli'...
Expo CLI installed. You can run `expo --help` for instructions.
This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]?
```

Any ideas why I'm having this?

Comment: Try this
`rm ~/.expo/log` and then use sudo to install expo, `sudo npm install expo-cli -g --unsafe-perm`

Comment: Thanks I tried, the installation is successful, but when I execute another `npm start` I still encounter the same problem, it still prompts for installing expo CLI...

Comment: Then you have the same problem as here
this will resolve your issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52534354/expo-cli-is-installed-globally-but-npm-start-command-still-asks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out my profile file was messed up (I had previously installed Anaconda which seems to have changed `.bash_profile` entries)
I removed all those stuff and inserted the correct $PATH that bash should look into. That was it.

Comment: Please help, I am facing the same problem and I don't really get how to remove those stuff!! Also where the path sould look into??

Answer (score 2):

Manually install expo-cli with `npm install expo-cli` before running `npm start`. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar issue. I have a few solutions. Try if they work out for you.

1. In case you have added the path multiple times remove it.
2. Ensure that there are no blank spaces or blank lines after the Path.(This one worked for me)

[image: Reference]