# Why can't zsh find expo?

Tags: npm, zsh, expo

I have installed `expo` and `expo-cli`.
I have set the `path` correctly, when i look into the `bin` directory i see `expo` and `expo-cli`.

But, I am having two problems, one is that expo goes into a continuous loop of installation whenever I try to run `npm start`.

Second, i am not able to run expo, even though it is in the path.
I read in an [answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59593996/endless-loop-on-installing-expo-cli) that this could be because path issues, but that is not the case, i have set the path correctly. Please see the screenshot of my terminal window.
[image]
Why is this happening?

Comment: @Aj : Aside of the correct explanation given by the answer from Gairfowl, note that zsh **does** run the command `expo`, otherwise you would get a _zsh: command not found_ error. It is in the sequel the command _expo_ which complains that something is missing.

Answer (score 0):

`~` is not a valid reference to the home directory in a `PATH`; it needs to be resolved prior to being included. Because of the `~`, the directory where `expo` and `expo-cli` are located is not actually in the path; that entry needs to look similar to some of the other entries, i.e. `/Users/<yourname>/.npm-global/bin`.

Here's a script that shows the difference; note the effect of the single quotes in the first `PATH` assignment:

```
echo 'echo in mytest' > ~/bin/mytest
chmod +x ~/bin/mytest

PATH='~/bin'
echo $PATH
#=> ~/bin
mytest
#=> command not found: mytest

PATH=~/bin
echo $PATH
#=> /Users/gairfowl/bin
mytest
#=> in mytest
```

Comment: So, should replace ~ with the resolved path? Not sure what I should do to fix this problem?

Comment: Yes, that's one way. In your `~/.zshrc` (or wherever you're setting the path), you can change the `~` in the PATH assignment for `.npm-global/bin` to `/Users/yourname`. Or you can remove the quotes in `.zshrc` that are preventing zsh from resolving the directory at the time `PATH` is assigned.